# How to use recursive to find the maximum number in a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, recursion, max

I am new to programming and I am learning python.

As an exercise, I am trying to write a recursive function that gets the maximum number in a list of numbers.

This is what I have tried, but it does not work correctly. Can somebody please guide me what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

P.S. I know this algorithm can be written by taking [1:] of the list elements, and I have found that on the internet. I want to know what's wrong with my way of doing it so I can learn from it. Thank you!

```
def get_max_in_list(data):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return data[0]
    number = data.pop()
    return number if number > get_max_in_list(data) else get_max_in_list(data)

data = [2, 6, 8, 3]
print(get_max_in_list(data))
```

Comment: "does not work correctly" doesn't really tell us anything...

Comment: Warning: regardless of correctness, a function that does not need to modify a list should not modify it. `pop` removes elements from your list, and the data you'll end up with after running your function will be very different from what you started with.

Comment: Warning 2: the solution you allude to that uses slices is a bad idea, because each slice creates a copy of a portion  of the list and that will pile up in memory. If you must recurse on a list, use indices and default values instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that each call of `get_max_in_list` modifies `data` by popping, which means the two calls `get_max_in_list(data)` in `return number if number > get_max_in_list(data) else get_max_in_list(data)` are operating on two different versions of `data`. You can fix this by storing the value so you only need to call it once, but a better option is to not modify the input.

```
def get_max_in_list(data):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return data[0]
    number = data.pop()
    m = get_max_in_list(data)
    return number if number > m else m
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not really supposed to modify an array while looking for its max value (though list.pop is doing that.). Probably your thoughts could be fit best with

```py
def get_max_in_list(data):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return data[0]

    return data[-1] if data[-1] > get_max_in_list(data[:-1]) else get_max_in_list(data[:-1])

data = [2, 6, 8, 3]
print(get_max_in_list(data))

print(data)
```

So that instead of deleting the value from list when accessing it, simply use backward indexing as `[1, 2, 3][-1]` returns 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might better recurse over this list using a start index (which defaults to 0 on first invocation), without modifying the list or making copies of slices from it:

```
def get_max_in_list(data, start_index=0):
    if start_index == len(data) - 1:
        return data[start_index]
    number = data[start_index]
    result = get_max_in_list(data, start_index + 1)
    return number if number > result else result

data = [2, 6, 8, 3]
print(get_max_in_list(data))
```